# What is the meaning of »hinten dran hängen«

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

I've seen this expression used in a few contexts, but can't seem to figure out the exact meaning. Could somebody translate the following sentences for me?

> 1. Einige meiner Projekte hängen hinten dran.
> 2. Soll ich nicht genommene Pillen hinten dranhängen?

Does this mean something like, to lag behind or leave behind? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The two examples translate via different meanings.

1: Some of my projects are trailing [behind the intended progress].

2: Should I tack on yet-untaken pills at the end [of taking the other pills]?

So, yes, lagging behind is the first meaning.

Answer (score 2):

> **dran**

.. is a short form for ***daran an***.

which makes

> **dranhängen**

a short form for ***daran anhängen***, in which the word »daran« (»*at it*« or »*on it*«) in fact is needless, since »anhängen« already means »*suspend*«, »*append*« or »*attach*«, i.e. »*to hang (something) on (something else)*« (which is the literal translation of »anhängen«), so the meaning of »daran« (»*at/on it*«) is already existent in the meaning of the word »anhängen« (»*append*«)

To say it shorter:

> dranhängen = anhängen

So your sentences mean exactly the same as those two:

> 1. Einige meiner Projekte hängen hinten an.
> 2. Soll ich nicht genommene Pillen hinten anhängen?

Both of your sentences are incomplete, because they do not contain the element to which the project or pills are appended.

I would complete them this way:

> 1. Einige meiner Projekte hängen *an den anderen* hinten dran/an.
> 2. Soll ich nicht genommene Pillen *an die genommenen* hinten dranhängen/anhängen?

If you translate those sentences, you get:

> 1. Some of my projects are appended *to the others*.
> 2. Do I need to append pills, that I did not take, *to the taken ones*?

I don't know if those sentences are good English (English is a foreign language to me), So I try to explain the meaning of the German sentences:

1. There are projects that are performed in a certain sequence. You also have (other) projects, and some of them will be performed in this sequence after the other projects.
2. In the past you have taken pills when it was necessary, but in the last few days you have forgotten to take the pills. Now you wonder, if you should take now the pills that you have forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Du hast es hier mit zwei unterschiedlichen Phrasen zu tun.

> **mit etwas** hinten dran hängen [Dat.]

d.h. spät dran sein mit etwas / Verspätung haben mit etwas / etwas spät machen (gegenüber dem Plan) / to be late with s.th.

> **etwas** hinten dran hängen [Akk.]

d.h. etwas hinten anfügen / hinten anfügen / etwas hinten dazufügen / to attach something at the rear end of something else (in deinem Beispiel: weitere Tabletten nehmen, nachdem man zuvor schon welche genommen hat).

Anmerkung: Über Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung kann man hier diskutieren. Der Duden von 1989 (also vor der sogenannten Rechtschreibreform) legt solche Wörter noch in Zusammenschreibung nahe, also ***hintendranhängen***.

Comment: In welchen Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums hat »hinten dran hängen« die Bedeutung »spät dran sein«? Mir war diese Bedeutung bis gerade eben völlig unbekannt.

Comment: **Mit** etwas hintendranhängen (aber unbedingt mit *mit*!) ist mir aus dem nicht gar so österreichfernen Süddeutschland durchaus vertraut. - "Kommst du mit raus in den Wald?" - "Nee, ich kann nicht, ich häng' total mit den Hausaufgaben hintendran."

Comment: PS. Ich gebe aber zu, dass die Variante, die der Fragesteller ins Spiel brachte ("Meine Projekte hängen hinten dran") auch mir ungewöhnlich (wenn nicht gar völlig neu) erscheint. Aber als abgeleitet von "Ich bin mit meinen Projekten hintendran" muss ich das wohl als akzeptabel... äh... akzeptieren.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich vermute auch, dass "mit etwas hinten dranhängen" sehr regional ist. Hier in Südwestdeutschland ist mir das noch nie begegnet und ich hatte mich beim Lesen der Frage zunächst gefragt: "An *was* hängen sie hinten dran?" Andererseits kenne ich die nicht allzu weit entfernte Formulierung "mit etwas hinterher sein".

Comment: Ich kenne: »(mit etwas) hinten sein« = »(mit etwas) in Verzug geraten sein«: »Ich bin ein bisschen hinten, ich habe erst 80 der bestellten 100 Stück fertig.« Ich kenne aber auch »hinterher sein« = »sorgfältig beobachten; verfolgen«: »Der Detektiv ist schon seit Wochen hinter dem Spion her.« und auch »dahinter sein« = »aufmerksam voranbringen, betreiben«: »Jürgen ist sehr dahinter, dass seine Tochter die Privatschule besuchen kann.« Ich kenne aber weder »mit etwas hinten dranhängen« (im von Christian beschriebenen Sinn) noch »mit etwas hinterher sein«.

Answer (score 1):

> Einige meiner Projekte hängen hinten dran.

In case of projects (e.g. IT projects) there are serval possibilities.
In my mind, the main meaning will be, that other projects or tasks had direct dependencies to the main project - so that they can't start before the project is finnished.

> Soll ich nicht genommene Pillen hinten dranhängen?

The meaning could be, if you take medicine (e.g. an antibiotic 10 pills, at morning / evening - so at least 5 days). In case you've forgotten 2 pills, there is the question to extent the medication to day 6, or stop taken the pills at day 5.